# SunOS free command

Tags: linux, perl, sparc, sunos

I have SunOS 5.10 sparc server. I want to calculate system memory. I can easily find this in Linux using /usr/bin/free command. Can anyone please suggest me if there is any equivalent command in SunOS. It would be better if anyone can give me any Perl script to find the same in below format.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2257920    1725688     532232          0     354736     766032
Swap:            0          0          0
Total:     2257920    1725688     532232
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'top' which can give you this information, but for this you need to install top package WLtop (if not already installed). You can find this in companion CD or you can download this from [sunfreeware.com](http://www.sunfreeware.com/)

This will be available in companion CD or you need to download from sunfreeware.com.

if this is already installed you can find the default top path would be

```
/usr/local/bin/top
```

If you want to use kstat, you can do below.

```
totalRAMPages = /usr/bin/kstat -p unix:0:system_pages:physmem
freeRAMPages = /usr/bin/kstat -p unix:0:system_pages:freemem 

pagesize = pagesize

totalRam in MB = totalRAMPages * pagesize / 1024 / 1024
freeRam in MB = freeRAMPages * pagesize / 1024 / 1024
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the physical memory information using `kstat -c pages`.  The numbers are in pages; use the `pagesize` command to get the page size in bytes.  Use `swap -s` for the current swap utilization.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any perl code to do find the required details in the same format as we get using free on linux.