# How to find Memory details using kstat on SunOS

Tags: perl, sun

With reference to my previous post "[SunOS free command](https://serverfault.com/questions/60771/sunos-free-command)" I need help to find the memory details using kstat command on sunOS.

I will really appreciate if anyone can help me with a perl script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ kstat -n system_pages
module: unix                            instance: 0     
name:   system_pages                    class:    pages
    availrmem                       398026
    crtime                          0
    desfree                         4078
    desscan                         25
    econtig                         4274913280
    fastscan                        261030
    freemem                         266772
    kernelbase                      3556769792
    lotsfree                        8157
    minfree                         2039
    nalloc                          25700723
    nalloc_calls                    18591
    nfree                           23835715
    nfree_calls                     11570
    nscan                           0
    pagesfree                       266772
    pageslocked                     124035
    pagestotal                      522061
    physmem                         522062
    pp_kernel                       125056
    slowscan                        100
    snaptime                        5003,716269185
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mdb` command to inspect the kernel memory:

```
# mdb -k
Loading modules: [ unix genunix specfs dtrace mac cpu.generic uppc pcplusmp scsi_vhci zfs sockfs ip hook neti sctp arp usba fctl md lofs fcip fcp cpc random crypto logindmux ptm ufs nsmb sppp sd ipc ]
> ::memstat
Page Summary                Pages                MB  %Tot
------------     ----------------  ----------------  ----
Kernel                     104261               407   40%
ZFS File Data               57894               226   22%
Anon                        68203               266   26%
Exec and libs                3715                14    1%
Page cache                  14851                58    6%
Free (cachelist)             1878                 7    1%
Free (freelist)              9180                35    4%

Total                      259982              1015
Physical                   259981              1015
```